# onsubmit does not trigger validate function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to write some code to validate data submitted in a HTML form.
However when I click the submit button the validation function doesn't run and the form is submitted.

```
function validate() {
    "use strict";

    var errMsg = "";
    var result = true;

    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;

    if (!firstname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        errMsg = errMsg + "your first name must only contain alpha characters\n";
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}


function init() {
    "use strict";

    var regForm = document.getElementById("submit");
    regForm.onsubmit = validate;

}

window.onload = init;
```

I made sure that the code was running by throwing in an alert and sure enough it worked. I'm having trouble seeing where the validation code is going wrong?

Note: I have to keep the JavaScript separate from the HTML.

Comment: The HTML code would help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dzjsxz1u/1/ - looks fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna guess:

```
var regForm = document.getElementById("submit");
```

if the id='submit' element is your submit button and not the form then that could be the issue.

Comment: That would solve it! Cant believe I was using submit instead of the form ID. Thanks for that aha.